# Counting Distinct Across Multiple Columns (Vertica SQL)

Tags: sql, count, distinct, vertica

Checked other questions without getting a clear answer.  I saw a simple answer using MySQL, but it doesn't work in Vertica.  Is there an efficient way to count distinct in vertica SQL across multiple columns.

For example, I know in MySQL you can do something like this:

```
SELECT l.computer, l.user, COUNT(DISTINCT l.computer, l.user) AS count
FROM login l 
GROUP BY l.computer, l.user
```

Is there a similar syntax in vertica?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: you should provide more detail

Comment: ok, will edit my question

Comment: This always return 1 for the count (in MySQL or Vertica). I'm assuming it's just a bad example. @kimbo305 has the answer, but I recommend always using a delimiter character just in case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just do this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT l.computer || l.user)
```

If you think it's possible that two different (computer, user) combos could produce the same string, use a prefix or delimiter.